# Verificación de binario no coincide, Apache NetBeans para Linux

Tags: linux, netbeans, apache, gpg

He descargado el instalador de Apache NetBeans para Linux. En la [página de descarga](https://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.cgi/netbeans/netbeans/12.3/Apache-NetBeans-12.3-bin-linux-x64.sh) dicen que hay que validar el archivo mediante varios métodos alternativos:

> It is essential that you verify the integrity of the downloaded file
> using the PGP signature (.asc file) or a hash (.md5 or .sha* file).

El método que me ha funcionado ha sido este:

```
gpg --print-md SHA256 downloaded_file
```

Pero cuando lo ejecuto me salen dos valores que no coinciden, algo así:

```
Apache-NetBeans-12.3-bin-linux-x64.sh: AEC86B9C CB1FC349 1B93AC59 79F820D5
                                       9EE593BE CD158A45 A3160526 E6330838
```

Por lo que considero que no es correcta la validación (a mi entender deberían coincidir).

¿Estoy errado en algo? ¿Por qué no coinciden? ¿Cómo podría validarlo?

Answer (score 3):

Me respondo a mi mismo por si puede servir a alguien.

### TL;DR

Simplemente hay que:

1. Descargar dos archivos: el de instalación y el que tiene la clave hash. Ambos archivos están en la página de descarga, pero puestos de una forma confusa uno al lado de los otros, las claves en los enlaces entre paréntesis como muestra la imagen más abajo.
2. Hacer una comparación entre ambos archivos, usando cualquiera de los métodos indicados [en esta página](https://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.cgi#verify).

La verificación más simple quizá sea esta (para el caso de Linux):

```
$ gpg --verify downloaded_file.asc downloaded_file
```

La salida indicará si el archivo está firmado correctamente o no (más abajo hay un ejemplo de salida por pantalla).

**NÓTESE** que en la página ellos sugieren antes un `--import`, pero esto **no es necesario si se descarga el `.asc` del enlace ([`PGP ASC`](https://archive.apache.org/dist/netbeans/netbeans/12.1/Apache-NetBeans-12.1-bin-linux-x64.sh.asc) para este caso)**.

Eso es todo...

---

Mi primer error fue no entender los enlaces que ofrece Apache en la página (tampoco es que ellos sean muy claros, porque lo tienen así):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

A la izquierda el enlace de descarga del archivo de instalación, y a la derecha, entre paréntesis, **varios enlaces**, que serían enlaces a las claves con las que habría que comparar.

Por un lado se descarga el archivo del enlace de la izquierda, cosa que ya había hecho. Y luego se verifica con uno de los métodos propuestos por Apache en [esta página](https://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.cgi/netbeans/netbeans/12.3/Apache-NetBeans-12.3-bin-linux-x64.sh).

> **MUY IMPORTANTE:** Hay que verificar que el archivo descargado coincide con la versión del archivo hash con el que se compara. Los
> nombres de archivo incluyen cada uno la versión, en este caso ambos
> tienen el valor `12.3` que es la versión de Netbeans.

Ejecutamos uno de los comandos sugeridos por Apache (en este también hay una confusión). La forma más simple de verificar es con el primer comando que se indica:

```
% gpg --import KEYS
% gpg --verify downloaded_file.asc downloaded_file
```

Sólo que el primer comando **no es necesario si se descarga el archivo `.asc`**. Ese primer comando parecería estar ahí para usarlo si se obtienen las claves [en esta forma](https://dist.apache.org/repos/dist/release/netbeans/KEYS).

Entonces, ignoramos ese primer comando y teniendo el instalador y el `.asc` en la misma carpeta, ejecutamos este comando simplemente:

```
$ gpg --verify Apache-NetBeans-12.3-bin-linux-x64.sh.asc Apache-NetBeans-12.3-bin-linux-x64.sh
```

La salida es:

```
gpg: Firmado el mar 02 mar 2021 18:04:37 CET
gpg:                usando RSA clave 7B037EEBE0F0DEDFEE65B6983703AC389A12A9D4
gpg:                emisor "neilcsmith@apache.org"
gpg: Firma correcta de "Neil C Smith <neilcsmith@apache.org>" [desconocido]
gpg: ATENCIÓN: ¡Esta clave no está certificada por una firma de confianza!
gpg:          No hay indicios de que la firma pertenezca al propietario.
Huellas dactilares de la clave primaria: 7B03 7EEB E0F0 DEDF EE65  B698 3703 AC38 9A12 A9D4
```

---

Se puede verificar también imprimiendo el hash, aunque esta forma es más complicada, sobre todo porque habría que comparar dos valores enormes:

```
$ gpg --print-md SHA512 Apache-NetBeans-12.3-bin-linux-x64.sh
```

La salida es:

```
Apache-NetBeans-12.3-bin-linux-x64.sh: E60DB3E9 B0A70C2D F03DB134 FA4F5E0C
                                       CB383E5D DBC03975 CB2012A0 A30176EC
                                       C73880D0 1D47814D 04C6F819 ABEE67EB
                                       CA946959 82043952 61F329DB 331C0157
```

Y comparamos con el hash del archivo indicado confusamente entre paréntesis en la página de descarga, que para el caso de SHA512 [es este](https://downloads.apache.org/netbeans/netbeans/12.3/Apache-NetBeans-12.3-bin-linux-x64.sh.sha512) (lo organizamos por grupos de 8 dígitos para comparar con más facilidad):

```
Apache-NetBeans-12.3-bin-linux-x64.sh: e60db3e9 b0a70c2d f03db134 fa4f5e0c     
                                       cb383e5d dbc03975 cb2012a0 a30176ec    
                                       c73880d0 1d47814d 04c6f819 abee67eb  
                                       ca946959 82043952 61f329db 331c0157
```

---

La verificación se puede hacer también según lo indicado [aquí](https://www.apache.org/info/verification.html):

> To check a hash, you have to compute the proper checksum of the file
> you just downloaded ; then compare it with the published checksum of
> the original.

Es decir, tengo que calcular el checksum con el comando apropiado según el tipo de cifrado y el sistema operativo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Para mi caso el comando sería este:

```
$ sha512sum Apache-NetBeans-12.3-bin-linux-x64.sh
```

La salida es:

> e60db3e9b0a70c2df03db134fa4f5e0ccb383e5ddbc03975cb2012a0a30176ecc73880d01d47814d04c6f819abee67ebca9469598204395261f329db331c0157 Apache-NetBeans-12.3-bin-linux-x64.sh

Y luego comparamos con el hash del enlace:

> e60db3e9b0a70c2df03db134fa4f5e0ccb383e5ddbc03975cb2012a0a30176ecc73880d01d47814d04c6f819abee67ebca9469598204395261f329db331c0157
> Apache-NetBeans-12.3-bin-linux-x64.sh

Comment: Yo sigo sin comprenderlo. Por lo que explican en la web el comando `gpg --print-md SHA256`  y  el `sha256sum`  hacen lo mismo, es decir son dos comandos para sacar por pantalla el checksum sha256 del fichero indicado, es normal que coincidan.  Sin embargo, en la tabla que muestras, la última columna dice **compare with** y yo creo que ese checksum habria que compararlo, en este caso, con el contenido del fichero *file.sha256*, pero no logro localizar dicho fichero. ¿no seria esto más lógico? el checksum hay que compararlo con un valor concreto y conocido de antemano ¿no?

Comment: @Fly, puede que tengas razón, aunque las explicaciones no son muy claras, esto *... then compare it with the published checksum of the original.* hace pensar que habría un hash publicado en alguna parte, pero no dicen donde ...

Answer (score 1):

Efectivamente el checksum hay que compararlo con uno facilitado en la propia página de descarga.

La versión 12.3 de Netbeans se descarga desde aquí: https://netbeans.apache.org/download/nb123/nb123.html

Y al lado de cada enlace de descarga está el enlace al fichero con el hash, aunque es este caso solo existe para [SHA-512](https://downloads.apache.org/netbeans/netbeans/12.3/Apache-NetBeans-12.3-bin-linux-x64.sh.sha512) y [PGP ASC](https://downloads.apache.org/netbeans/netbeans/12.3/Apache-NetBeans-12.3-bin-linux-x64.sh.asc).

Al parecer las especificaciones descritas en la página principal de Apache (https://www.apache.org/info/verification.html#CheckingHashes), son genéricas y no es seguida exactamente por todos los proyectos, Netbeans solo provee un par de *checksums* así que no podrás usar el SHA256 mencionado.

Comment: Me di cuenta sobre los enlaces al lado del enlace de descarga, puestos entre paréntesis (lo cual confunde) y estoy peleando con ellos, tratando de entender el proceso. O las explicaciones de Apache son muy complicadas para mi o están hechas para expertos en Linux... el hecho es que lo encuentro demasiado confuso. He descargado y copiado/pegado el contenido de los enlaces entre paréntesis e intentando varios de los procesos de verificación y ninguno funciona, unos dan error y los que funcionan dicen que no tienen la misma firma o que la firma es incorrecta.

Comment: Como nota, en tu pregunta el enlace para `PGP ASC` es el de Windows, en mi caso aplicarían los de Linux.

Comment: Por ejemplo, según la página de descarga, [este es el enlace](https://archive.apache.org/dist/netbeans/netbeans/12.1/Apache-NetBeans-12.1-bin-linux-x64.sh.sha512) del `SHA512`, dice que hay que ejecutar este comando `gpg --print-md SHA512 Apache-NetBeans-12.3-bin-linux-x64.sh` y comparar la salida con lo que muestra el enlace. Al hacer eso la clave que imprime en pantalla no coincide. No entiendo entonces cómo es que la página de descarga ofrece archivos no coincidentes ¿?

Comment: Ya di con el problema, estaba comparando con el archivo SHA512 de la versión 12.1, y tengo descargado el archivo de la versión 12.3

Comment: Editado y corregido el enlace  PGP, gracias @A.Cedano

Comment: He editado la respuesta. Me parece que las explicaciones de Apache son algo confusas.